# New application has a warning under the Services tree in solution explorer

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I created a brand new Service Fabric application with a stateless service in Visual Studio 2017. I can compile the application and run it on my local cluster and it runs normally. For some reason the Services tree structure shows a warning for the service, though:

[image: service warning]

Where can I find out what this warning is for? It doesn't show up in the Warnings section when I compile the code.

Comment: What happens if you `remove` the `SampleStateless` service and then again `Add an existing service` to it?

Comment: Still a warning.

Comment: Check you service fabric sdk version might be that

Comment: @duongthaiha Service Fabric SDK is the most recent version as is the runtime